# webbrowser.open_new(filename) doesn't work inside a flask docker container?

Tags: docker, flask, python-webbrowser

I have a flask api with an endpoint that creates a pdf invoice file. I use webbrowser.open_new(filename) to open the pdf in browser, and that works fine when I run it outside the container. But if run it with docker it doesn't work. Here are my files:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from api_pdf import InvoicePDF
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

invoice_pdf_routes = [f'/hello']
api.add_resource(InvoicePDF, *invoice_pdf_routes)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

api_invoice.py

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from datetime import datetime
import pdfkit
import webbrowser

class InvoicePDF(Resource):
    def create_pdf(self):
        pdf_content = """<html> <head><body>Invoice</body></html>"""
        invoice_date = str(datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
        filename = "invoice_" + invoice_date + '.pdf'
        options = {
                "enable-local-file-access": ""
        }
        pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, filename, options=options)
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
        return filename
    def get(self):
        self.create_pdf()
        return True
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV WERKZEUNG_RUN_MAIN=true \
        PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
        PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 \
        FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0 \
        FLASK_APP=app.py
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install wkhtmltopdf -y && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

requirements.txt

```
flask>=1.1.2,<2.0.0
flask-restful
pdfkit
markupsafe==2.0.1
```

What I am doing:

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -p 5000:5000 test
```

and on postman I do:
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello

expected result:
request return True and a new browser tab open with invoice pdf file

what happens:
request return True but new browser tab doesn't open

Why does this not work inside the container? Should I be using something other than *webbrowser.open_new(filename)* or am I going about this completely wrong? I don't want to save the pdf in a DB and have to call that.

Comment: A container is an enclosed environment. Opening a browser on the host is not allowed.

Comment: Oh okay, might be a very obvious question but for context the container is deployed and through adding this endpoint I wanted the client's browser to open the invoice_pdf that gets generated (without saving in db). Is that not possible?

Comment: You'd have to do that in client-side code.  Even without a container involved, the `webbrowser.open_new_tab()` call wouldn't work if the browser and server were on different systems.